# Order by meta field alphabetically with multipel meta field conditions

Tags: wordpress

I'd like give my WP-Query something that the result is ordered alphabetically by a meta value (nwswa_reservation_event) of the post type. Until now I have this functioning query:

```
$args_nwswa_reservations = array (
    // Post or Page ID
    'post_type' => 'nwswa_reservation',
    'meta_key'  => 'nwswa_reservation_event',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
                    'relation' => 'AND',
                    'post_id' => array(
                        'key'     => 'nwswa_reservation_event',
                        'value' => $post_id,
                        'compare' => '=',
                    ),
                    'post_status' => array(
                        'key'     => 'nwswa_reservation_status',
                        'value' => 'storniert',
                        'compare' => '!=',
                    ), 
                ),

);
```

Hope you can help me further.

Best wishes
Lukas

Answer (score 1):

```
$args_nwswa_reservations = array (
// Post or Page ID
    'post_type' => 'nwswa_reservation',
    'meta_key'  => 'nwswa_reservation_event',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                'post_id' => array(
                    'key'     => 'nwswa_reservation_event',
                    'value' => $post_id,
                    'compare' => '=',
                ),
                'post_status' => array(
                    'key'     => 'nwswa_reservation_status',
                    'value' => 'storniert',
                    'compare' => '!=',
                ), 
            ),

);
```

Comment: `'order' => 'ACS'` should be `'order' => 'ASC'`

Comment: Thanks @CornelRaiu